# what is common approach to handle edit user in list of users in web applications (based on Java)?

Tags: css, html, forms, jsp, jstl

Each web aplication with users need implement some action which can be called from the list of users. Like this:

```
Login   Name    Lastname   Options
user1   name1   lastname1  ViewProfile Follow Ban
user2   name2   lastname2  ViewProfile Follow Ban
user3   name3   lastname3  ViewProfile Follow Ban
```

List of users is generated from javabean which in which is output from database. The easiest way to imagine list of users, their atributs and options which we can do with users is table. The task is implementation calling the actions (ViewProfile, Follow, Ban, ...) on specific user. Calling an action will transfer the control to appropriate servlet. (So I'have servlets for ViewProfile, Follow user, Ban user ...). Servlet just prepare data and forward it to some jsp page. Theres no problem. Problem could be with information what user profile should be viewed or what user should be followed by loged user (just give the servlet info about the user_id).

I found two approches which can be used (maybe there are more): 
1) Using ViewProfile and the table will be really represented as table in html. 
2) Using form for each action. In this case for tree users I will have 9 forms.
Each form will have input type="hidden" with value set as user_id for transfering the user_id and submit button. Method will be post.

Advantages and dissadvantages of sollutions:
1)Easy to write it. But the parametter is in url and method could be only get.
2)I could use method post. But I can't use table as in first case, because it's not possible to have form inside  tag.

What is best approach to format the second case like a table (like first case)? 
Or if there is better way to solve this than my two options, what is it?

I use Java 7, Tomcat 7, Servlets, JSP and jslt, html5 and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Of your three actions (*ViewProfile*, *Follow*, *Ban*), the first sounds like a candidate for a GET while the other two sound like POST actions.

For POSTing to the *Follow* and *Ban* servlets (and *ViewProfile*, if desired), you could make use of forms oustide of the table which are populated and submitted via JavaScript on a *click* event.

```
<form id="followForm" action="...follow.do" method="post">
    <input id="followUserId" type="hidden" value="-1" />
</form>

<form id="banForm" action="...ban.do" method="post">
    <input id="banUserId" type="hidden" value="-1" />
</form>
```

Attach a *click* listener to the links (via a class name) which sets the hidden field and submits the form.

```
$(".followLink").click(function() {
    $("#followUserId").val($(this).prev().prev().text()); // navigate the table to get the user login id
    $("#followForm").submit();
});
```

Note that this solution uses jQuery for simplicity, but this could also be done without an external JavaScript library using *onclick* and a little more work.